# Get Highest Res Favicon

Tags: api, web-applications, graphics, favicon

I'm making a website that needs to dynamically obtain the favicon of sites upon request. I've found a few api's that can accomplish this fairly well, and so far I'm liking http://www.fvicon.com/.

The final image for my website will be 64x64px, and some websites such as Google and Wordpress have nice images of this size that are easily retrieved via this api. Though, of course, most websites only have a 16x16 favicon image and scaling that image to 64x64 has very bad quality loss.

Examples:

(high res) http://a.fvicon.com/wordpress.com?format=png&width=64&height=64

(low res)  http://a.fvicon.com/yahoo.com?format=png&width=64&height=64

Keeping this in mind, I'm planning on somehow determining whether a high-res image is available and, if so, the website will use this image. If not, I want to use a pre-made 64x64 icon with the smaller icon layered over it. What I'm having trouble with is determining if there is a high res favicon available or not.

Also, I'm curious if there's a better approach to this situation. I'd rather not use smaller images (64x64 works out really well for this project). The lowest res I'm willing to drop to is 48x48 but even then there will be a significant quality loss for scaling up  16x16 favicons.

Any ideas? If you need any more information I will gladly provide it.

Thank you!

Comment: In both links you provided it seems the icons have the same resolution ?

Comment: @userSeven7s is your problem the same than Jeremy? If so, could you provide favicon with 16*16, 32*32 and 64*64 res files?

Comment: Interesting idea, but I'm wondering if you're trying to create a solution for a problem that doesn't exist - if the sites don't have a 64x64 favicon then that's their problem. 

I appreciate that your site may not look as good, so would be happy to look at a solution with you though. What server platform are you working with?

Comment: It looks like both links are down

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://blog.55minutes.com/2012/01/multi-resolution-favicons-and-safaris-reading-list/)'s a link to a way of **using** favicons in different resolutions. Maybe it helps you to find out how to get them. You would have to search the website's code (don't know how to do this) for `/<link.*rel="icon".*>/` and search in the root directory of the webserver for favicon.ico. (I hope the regex is correct)

Hope I can help you.

Answer (score 1):

PHP has a native function called `getimagesize`. If you can retrieve the favicon, then you can run the function and determine if it's high res or not and act accordingly.

Just a thought.

Answer (score -1):

This is late to the party, but grabicon.com works very similarly to fvicon, but returns the image size you want without quality degradation. It adds a matching border around the smaller image to give you the icon size you require, so the icons on your web page all "match". If a site doesn't have an icon, grabicon creates a unique one for it.

Full disclosure, I'm grabicon's creator, but it's free and gives you what you're asking for :)

Comment: It's paid actually. Starting from $9/mo.